# Is there a different method to increase run performance in R?

Tags: r

I'm collecting some Economic indicator data. In this process, I also want to collect hourly tweet counts with the script. I asked a similar question with simple data before. As the historical data grows, the run times will get longer. Since the result table will be a dataframe, can I run this script more effectively with functions such as **apply** family or **do.call**?

```
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

sel1<-c('"#fed"','"#usd"','"#ecb"','"#eur"')

for (i in sel1) 
{
  for (ii in 1:20){
    headers = c(
      `Authorization` = 'Bearer #enter your Bearer token#'
    )
    
    params = list(
      `query` =i,
       #my sys.time is different
      `start_time` = strftime(Sys.time()-(ii+1)*60*60, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",tz ='GMT'),
      `end_time` =strftime(Sys.time()-ii*60*60, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",tz ='GMT'),
      `granularity` = 'hour'
    )
    
    res1<- httr::GET(url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params) %>% 
      content( as = 'parsed')
    x1<-cbind(data.frame(res1),topic=str_replace_all(i, "([\n\"#])", ""))
    
    if(!exists("appnd1")){
      appnd1 <- x1
    } else{
      appnd1 <- rbind(appnd1, x1)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, iteratively `rbind`-ing data in a `for` loop will always get worse with time: each time you do one `rbind`, it copies all of the previous frame into memory, so you have two copies of everything. With small numbers this is not so bad, but you can imagine that copying a lot of data around in memory can be a problem. (This is covered in the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), chapter 2, *Growing objects*. It's good reading, even if it is not a recent document.)

The best approach is to create a list of frames (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227), add contents to it, and then when you are done combine all frames within the list into a single frame.

Untested, but try this modified process:

```r
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

sel1<-c('"#fed"','"#usd"','"#ecb"','"#eur"')

listofframes <- list()

for (i in sel1) {
  for (ii in 1:20){
    headers = c(
      `Authorization` = 'Bearer #enter your Bearer token#'
    )
    
    params = list(
      `query` =i,
       #my sys.time is different
      `start_time` = strftime(Sys.time()-(ii+1)*60*60, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",tz ='GMT'),
      `end_time` =strftime(Sys.time()-ii*60*60, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ",tz ='GMT'),
      `granularity` = 'hour'
    )
    
    res1<- httr::GET(url = 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/counts/recent', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), query = params) %>% 
      content( as = 'parsed')
    x1<-cbind(data.frame(res1),topic=str_replace_all(i, "([\n\"#])", ""))
    listofframes <- c(listofframes, list(x1))
  }
}

# choose one of the following based on your R-dialect/package preference
appnd1 <- do.call(rbind, listofframes)
appnd1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(listofframes)
appnd1 <- data.table::rbindlist(listofframes)
```